# Could not publish to the server. Cannot acquire J2EEFlexProjDeployable object

Tags: java, tomcat

I use the  myEclipse version 2015 CI 17 and I install apache tomcat 8.0.
However when I try to run a simple web project demo. I encounter some problems.

Here are the detail informations:

Could not publish to the server.
Cannot acquire J2EEFlexProjDeployable object for module MyFirstWebApp [EXPLODED on Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost]
Cannot acquire J2EEFlexProjDeployable object for module MyFirstWebApp [EXPLODED on Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost]

And I can't solve it.

Comment: Okay problem solved. I think it's because that I have already start Tomcat before. After I shutdown the Tomcat and run the demo, everything runs well.

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is some kind of state issue. For what it's worth, I solved this issue by removing the deployment and then adding it again. I don't know why it worked but it did :)

Comment: Worked for me.  Sometimes the simplest solutions are most effective.